# How to get list of installed RPM packages with Java

Tags: java, linux, rpm

Is there a way to get a list of the installed packages using Java? I would like to assess the internal Linux database and get this information. Using simple java code is not a option in my case.

```
Process rpmProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rpm -qa");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rpmProc.getInputStream()));

String package;
while ((package = input.readLine()) != null) {
    // .. do something
}
```

Is there a way to access this information in lower level of the OS using Java?

Comment: *Why* is the simple code not an option? If you don't tell us, then you're unlikely to get an alternative that's useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the package database file inside your user `$HOME`, the files are stored under `$HOME/.rpmdb`. These files can be read by [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) software

Answer (score 0):

If by Linux you mean Linux kernel, then there is no such database. Installation is managed by package managers like rpm, deb, pac etc. These maintain their own databases in files like you accessed it in your code using rpm. Their is no System Low Level API for that and should not exist either as package management is not the job of the kernel.